Double integral of projectile problem
Given the projectile problem
$$x^{\prime \prime}=-\frac{1}{(1+\epsilon x)^{2}}$$
$$x(0) = 0 \quad x^{\prime}(0) = 1$$
By integrating twice, the projectile problem can be rewritten as the integral equation
$$x(t) = t - \int^{t}_{0}\int^{\tau}_{0}\frac{ds}{(1+\epsilon x(s))^{2}}d\tau = t - \int^{t}_{0} \frac{(t- \tau)d\tau}{(1+\epsilon x(\tau))^{2}}$$
The previous was a statement I found in my applied analysis notes. I understand what we are doing, but I'm not sure how the professor managed to reach the second result of the double integral.

Change the order of integration, then $s$ can freely be swapped out for $\tau$ or any other variable:
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{\tau=0}^t \int_{s=0}^\tau \frac{ds \, d\tau}{(1+\epsilon x(s))^2} &= \int_{s=0}^t \int_{\tau=s}^t \frac{d\tau \, ds}{(1+\epsilon x(s))^2} \\
&= \int_0^t \frac{t-s}{(1+\epsilon x(s))^2} \, ds \\
&= \int_0^t \frac{t-\tau}{(1+\epsilon x(\tau))^2} \, d\tau
\end{align*}$$
